# Returning std::make_pair with std::forward

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a function that will return pair containing two data types, where first type is always the same, but second is template-type. Is that even possible? (I'm also wondering if my understanding of `std::forward` usage is correct). For better demonstrating of my problem I'll show you simplified sample of my (not working) code.

Here's what I tried:

```
template <class X>
std::pair<int, X> func(X&& second)
{
    int first = 1;
    return std::make_pair(std::move(first), std::forward<X>(second));
}
```

Inside function, I create variable `first` and then I want to return pair. Here I move `first` - to avoid copying - and (following Scott Meyers' lecture where he explained `std::forward` as an "conditional move")  depending if parameter `second` was l-value I want to pass `second` as an l-value (to let `std::make_pair` make copy of `second`, when creating pair) or if it was r-value I want to pass "moved" r-value.

Unfortunately my code doesn't work. I think I must have misunderstood something, but I don't know what, can you explain me, please?

Comment: "my code doesn't work" - What doesn't work? What's the error message?

Comment: @Rakete1111 The problem was passing to func l-value argument - it was deduced by `std::make_pair` as a reference. Issue solved thanks to skypjack.

Comment: @mdjdrn1 Anyway Rakete1111 is right, pay attention and post the error message along with your question next time. It will help those that come to help. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you want a *C++14-ish* `std::decay_t` or a `std::remove_reference_t` in your declaration:

```
template <class X>
std::pair<int, std::decay_t<X>> func(X&& second) {
    int first = 1;
    return std::make_pair(std::move(first), std::forward<X>(second));
}
```

Or the C++11, more verbose, but equivalent version:

```
template <class X>
std::pair<int, typename std::decay<X>::type> func(X&& second) {
    int first = 1;
    return std::make_pair(std::move(first), std::forward<X>(second));
}
```

This way, no matter if you are using an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference to `X` as an actual parameter of `func`, your `std::pair` will use `X` as a type.

---

Note that you can't use a reference to `X` as a type of a `std::pair`.
Let's consider the following example:

```
#include<utility>

template <class X>
std::pair<int, X> func(X&& second) {
    int first = 1;
    return std::make_pair(std::move(first), std::forward<X>(second));
}

int main() {
    int i = 42;
    func(i);
}
```

In this case, `X` is deduced as `int &`. Return type is thus `std::pair<int, int &>`, that is not allowed and doesn't compile.

The following will compile instead:

```
template <class X>
std::pair<int, std::remove_reference_t<X>> func(X&& second) {
    int first = 1;
    return std::make_pair(std::move(first), std::forward<X>(second));
}
```

This is because `X` is still deduced as `int &`, but the return type is now adjusted to `std::pair<int, int>`.

Comment: I've tested it for both `std::decay_t` and `std::remove_reference_t` and works perfectly. I didn't notice before that, when I was passing to func l-value it was deduced as a reference. Big thanks!

Comment: @mdjdrn1 They differ in the purpose, so have a look at the documentation for further details. And... you are welcome. ;-)